# Stopping script once color is no longer found in BufferedImage Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, bufferedimage

I currently have a script that takes a screencap of an area and searches that area for every color value. However, I want the script to stop running once a specific color is not found in *any* area of the image. My current script stops the moment that a pixel is not the correct color, which is not what I want.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 1){
        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        BufferedImage image2 = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(70, 102,200,222));
\        for (int y = 0; y < image2.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image2.getWidth(); x++) {
                Color pixcolor = new Color(image2.getRGB(x, y));
                int red = pixcolor.getRed();
                int green = pixcolor.getGreen();
                int blue = pixcolor.getBlue();
                System.out.println("Red  = " + red);
                System.out.println("Green  = " + green);
                System.out.println("Blue  = " + blue);

                if (red == 253 && green == 222 && blue == 131){
                            continue;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println(x);
                            System.out.println(y);
                            i ++;
                            System.exit(1);;
                        }

    }
}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work. Basically I just use boolean 'isFound' to remember 
if the color is found in the picture, if it is not, then the while loop ends.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException {
        boolean isFound = false; // before was Boolean isNotFound = true;
        while (!isFound) {
            BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            BufferedImage image2 = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(70, 102, 200, 222));
            isFound = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < image2.getHeight(); y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < image2.getWidth(); x++) {
                    Color pixcolor = new Color(image2.getRGB(x, y));
                    int red = pixcolor.getRed();
                    int green = pixcolor.getGreen();
                    int blue = pixcolor.getBlue();
                    System.out.println("Red  = " + red);
                    System.out.println("Green  = " + green);
                    System.out.println("Blue  = " + blue);

                    if (red == 253 && green == 222 && blue == 131) {
                        isFound = true;
                        break;
                    }


                }
                if (isFound) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: apparently by accident I declared isFound as isNotFound in that code. so if you just change isNotFound to isFound

Comment: I'm new to Java. While I think that the code should work, it doesn't seem to?